# http method GET is not supported by URL

Tags: servlets

I run the servlet ,at the time of running it shows error 405 http method Get is not supported but ager refreshing changes is occured which is required in servlet.Why this is happening?

Please Help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you have put method ='post' and are doing a post request while trying to handle that using doGet ? . Ty remoing the method=post or override the dpPost method . If this is not the issue, please post your code.